# How to change the orientation of the interface through code in iPad

Tags: iphone, orientation

Hello
I am wondering if it is possible to change the orientation of the interface through code in iPhone/iPad.i.e,for example i have a button.if i click on that my interface orientation should change.if it is possible please help me how to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pls go through this

[Is there a documented way to set the iPhone orientation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181780/is-there-a-documented-way-to-set-the-iphone-orientation)

There is an undocumented property setter on UIDevice that does the trick but obviously generates a compiler warning and could disappear with a future revision of the SDK.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
```

Another link [Forcing UIInterfaceOrientation changes on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689598/forcing-uiinterfaceorientation-changes-on-iphone) which may help you

Comment: these are the compiler warnings that lead directly into rejection.