# Lock screen Orientation to portrait - ios swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, screen-orientation

I am creating an application with support only for portrait mode. I don't want Landscape or Portrait upside down. I tried some code. Which allows me to lock in portrait mode.

I am using navigationcontroller and presentviewcontroller. Now my problem is:
1. If I rotate my device upside down and open my application it opens in upside down mode which is wrong.
2. I click some button and enter to presentviewcontroller it returns to portrait mode.

**I want all the navigationcontroller and presentviewcontroller in portrait mode**

My codes:

I set device orientarion portrait in `Target -> General -> Deployment Info -> Portrait`

**In my appdelagate.swift:**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
    }
```

In my First view controller. Which is basically child of Navigation Controller

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {


            return false
        }

        override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
            return [UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait ]
        }
```

Edit 1:

Also I set `StoryBoard -> ViewController -> Attribute Inspector -> Orientation -> Portrait`

Edit 2:

My settings file 
[image]

Comment: check this one also its working for me
[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938660/how-to-lock-orientation-of-one-view-controller-to-portrait-mode-only-in-swift)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Go To Target --> General and set Orientation Mode to Portrait.

[image]

Also check info.plist. Make sure `Supported Interface Orientations` contains only one value(Portrait). Sometime it removes from settings but not updated in plist file.

[image]

Comment: Please check Info.plist file as suggested in answer. This may be case with you.

Comment: Thanks Just I missed a single line and complete app went weird. I am new to ios thanks.

Comment: In my case there was an additional option for iPads that allowed all orientation types. So I left only the `Portrait (bottom home button)` and everything is working perfectly now.

Answer (score 3):

If your app is not supporting split screen view than you should check the option to Require full screen. This fixed my issue with portrait mode.
[image]

If this does not resolve issue add **Supported interface orientations** Key of Array type in your info.plist. And String item to that array with value **Portrait (bottom home button)**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Just I missed a single line and complete app went weird. I am new to ios thanks. Technerd add solutios 1 minute before you So I accept his answer. I upvoted You.

Answer (score 0):

For me the only working solution was to add:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    .portrait
}
```

in the app's delegate class, as indicated in the question itself.

I'm using **SwiftUI** without any storyboard file, even for the splashscreen.