# I have the device orientation of my app (iOS/ Swift) set to portrait only, however the screen still rotates?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

[Picture of deployment settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zaksp.png)

As you can see in the picture, I have set my device orientation to portrait only, but the app will still rotate. I am coding completely programmatically, so there is no storyboard. Any Ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lock screen Orientation to portrait - ios swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35285392/lock-screen-orientation-to-portrait-ios-swift)

Answer (score 0):

After some headache I found that the reason it was acting up was because, I had not selected A Main interface in the "general" Target menu. This mistake started because I had deleted my storyboard to code UI programmatically. If you do the same select "LaunchScreen.storyboard", and your app will work normal.