# How do I lock screen orientation from Cordova plugin?

Tags: ios, swift, cordova

I'm writing a Cordova plugin, which simply presents a UIView controller. I can lock the orientation of that UIView, but can I also lock its parent's orientation?

in main Cordova class:

```
self.storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "myuiview", bundle: nil)
self.myView = self.storyboard?.instantiateInitialViewController() as? myViewController
self.viewController.present(self.myView!, animated: true) { _ in }
```

in myViewController:

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .portrait
}

override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return .portrait
}
```

This locks the orientation of current myViewController. However when I rotate the device and then `dismiss` myViewController, the orientation of the app still changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think below post also resolves your issue.

You can revise @bmjohns's answer

[How to lock orientation of one view controller to portrait mode only in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938660/how-to-lock-orientation-of-one-view-controller-to-portrait-mode-only-in-swift/41811798#41811798)