# How to make the screen vertically only. (UITabBarController/Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

When I use UITabbarController, I'd like to display only the portrait screen without rotating the screen.

When I am not using UITabBarController, I do not rotate the screen and it is in landscape view.

Therefore, I set the following for ViewController not using UITabBarController.

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    get {
        return true
    }
}
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    get {
        return .landscapeRight
    }
}
```

In the specifications of the application, we make the following settings.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXVOW.png)

I am using UITabbarController in storyboard 1.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ModtI.png)

I am not using UITabbarController in storyboard 2.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK8Q2.png)

I'd like to create an application to move from storyboard 1 to storyboard 2.

I do not know how to display the screen vertically only on the ViewController that I use UITabBarController.

Comment: May this question will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938660/how-to-lock-orientation-of-one-view-controller-to-portrait-mode-only-in-swift

Comment: @MoayadAlkouz Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suggest you to create an extension

```
extension UITabBarController {
  override open var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
      return .portrait
  }
}
```

usage :

```
 let tabbar = UITabBarController.init()
  _ = tabbar.supportedInterfaceOrientations
```

or

```
tabbar.supportedInterfaceOrientations = .portrait
```

Comment: I was able to set the vertical screen.
However, I had a new problem.
I would like to create another question because the explanation of the problem will be long.
Thank you for your advice.