# SwiftUI: How to force Landscape without AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swiftui, rotation

I am making app with Video Player in it and my whole struct is made for only portrait view, except this video player. I want to enable landscape rotation just for this view. But I've chacked lots of forums and every answere was to add some code to App Delegate, and i don't have it. What can i do then.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a demo for you. You can change the orientation to the one you like by calling the function `changeOrientation`. You can also reverse an orientation change after it's done, using the `.onReceive`. The `.onReceive` is called every time there is an orientation change, so you can reverse a orientation change that you don't like.
I know this is not optimal, but this is the best i could find without using a lot of UIKit and AppDelegate. You can use AppDelegate for a better result (i think).

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct ContentView: View {
    
    private let rotationChangePublisher = NotificationCenter.default
        .publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)
    @State private var isOrientationLocked = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Change orientation") {
                if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait {
                    changeOrientation(to: .landscapeLeft)
                } else {
                    changeOrientation(to: .portrait)
                }
            }.padding()
            
            Button("Orientation is \(isOrientationLocked ? "" : "NOT ")Locked to portrait-only") {
                isOrientationLocked.toggle()
            }.padding()
        }
        .font(.system(size: 17, weight: .semibold))
        .onReceive(rotationChangePublisher) { _ in
            // This is called when there is a orientation change
            // You can set back the orientation to the one you like even
            // if the user has turned around their phone to use another
            // orientation.
            if isOrientationLocked {
                changeOrientation(to: .portrait)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func changeOrientation(to orientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
        // tell the app to change the orientation
        UIDevice.current.setValue(orientation.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
        print("Changing to", orientation.isPortrait ? "Portrait" : "Landscape")
    }
}
```

Also, make sure you've allowed different orientations that you'd like to use, beforehand:

[image]

Comment: Everything works perfectly but it's not quite what i was looking for. I wanted to enable rotating just in this video view. And now my whole project can do that, and everything i did wasn't prepared for landscape view. So is there anyway to disable rotating in rest view. Or just enable there.

Comment: @green8: that is easy, you have to lock your project to Portrait in Xcode project setting, and you should rotate that View 90 degree, that is it

Comment: that could work, although that is not optimal neither. I think doing it the UIKit way is the best approach but green8 was asking for not-UIKit way so i tried my best.

Comment: @green8 if you don't know already, you can add AppDelegate to a SwiftUI app quite easily. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-an-appdelegate-to-a-swiftui-app. Don't be afraid to learn how to use AppDelegate if you dont know how to work with it, because SwiftUI can't do a bunch of things without AppDelegate and you'll probably need it going forward in your app.

Comment: @MahdiBM I actually tried that before, but i gave it one more chance and found my mistake. I did it properly and it worked!!! This is link where i found the solution for whole problem if someone would have the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59634088/14480820. Thank you for help.

Comment: This solution works but sadly it's broken in ios16

Answer (score 4):

iOS 16 (and above)

```
Button("Force landscape") {
    guard let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene else { return }
    windowScene.requestGeometryUpdate(.iOS(interfaceOrientations: .landscape))
}
```

Comment: Please describe why this code works and how to properly use it.

Comment: Just run this code and that's it. What else is there to describe?

Comment: That actually worked pretty well. I had a view where I needed to force landscape. I added this code to onAppear, and voila! Thank you.

Comment: This works well for the first time, but a later attempt to call it for portrait fails with a logged error stating that the new UIInterfaceOrientationMask is not supported by the view

Comment: A solution to my previous comment is to have a didSet for orientationLock, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75314986/3765705) answer.