# SwiftUI set device orientation

Tags: swiftui, screen-orientation

I’m trying to find a way to set the orientation of the device in my SwiftUI app.

I was following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75270101/swiftui-force-device-rotation-programmatically?newreg=ca187390fa874e44888e80c1410f76b5) but the function `UIViewController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()` is deprecated. XCode tells me to use `setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations()` instead but I’m not sure how to do so. Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Comment: If your app needs to support iOS versions below 16, you may as well stay with the deprecated function.
If you only support 16+, then look at this solution instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73649566/ios-16-scene-orientation-issue