# Force landscape orientation in one View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, device-orientation

In my App all Views are forced to portrait orientation via info.plist.

The exception should be "MyView" which should always be in landscape orientation.

What I did after taking a deeper look in SO:

**Added in AppDelegate.swift:**

```
static var orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait 

func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return AppDelegate.orientationLock
}
```

**MyView.swift**

```
struct MyView: View {
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        // ...Some Images, etc.
    }
    .onAppear(perform: orientationLandscape)
    .onDisappear(perform: orientationPortrait)
}

func orientationLandscape() {
    AppDelegate.orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeRight
    UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight, forKey: "orientation")
    UINavigationController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
}

func orientationPortrait() {
    AppDelegate.orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
    UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait, forKey: "orientation")
    UINavigationController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
}
```

}

UIDevice.current.setValue produces an error. 
Without that line I can change the orientation in MyView manually by holding the device in landscape/portrait but it should switch automatically when opening and closing the View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by orientating on [bmjohns answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41811798/12637422) on a similar question:

1. Add some code in AppDelegate (this part i had already)
2. Make a struct and func which does the job (small adjustments for XCode 11 and SwiftUI were needed)
3. Execute the func onAppear of your View

Comment: What adjustments did you need to make in step 2 to get this working with SwiftUI?

Comment: Can you elaborate on step2 ?

Answer (score 2):

Since some info is missing on accepted answer i will put what i used in Swift 5

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


    var orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return orientationLock
    }
}

struct AppUtility {

    static func orientationLandscape() {
        if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
                delegate.orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeRight
        }
        UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
        UINavigationController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
    }
    
    static func orientationPortrait() {
        if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
                delegate.orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
        }
        UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
        UINavigationController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
    }

}

.onAppear(perform: {
            AppUtility.orientationLandscape()
        }).onDisappear(perform: {
            AppUtility.orientationPortrait()
        })
```

Opening a view

```
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented) {
                                NavigationLazyView(aView())
                            }
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a way for Force landscape orientation

Put the code in `viewDidLoad()`

```
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue
UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

and also,

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}
```

**for SwiftUI**

We set the project orientation to only support Portrait mode.

Then in your AppDelegate add an instance variable for orientation and conform to the supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor delegate method.

```
static var orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait

func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return AppDelegate.orientationLock
}
```

Then when your about to present your landscape view perform the following actions:

```
AppDelegate.orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeLeft
UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft, forKey: "orientation")
UINavigationController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
```

And on dismissal,

```
AppDelegate.orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait, forKey: "orientation")
UINavigationController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
```

Hope this will help you ...:)

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. This sounds like a UIKit-Solution for me. Where do you put this code snippets in SwifUI? There is no viewDidLoad().

Comment: In your edited answer there is not a single line different to my code which I have written in my question...this leads to the following error "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" "orientationLock UIInterfaceOrientationMask [.landscapeLeft]" in AppDelegate when I open the view through my NavigationLink.