# Swift 5, lock first VC to Potrait mode, other VC support all orientations

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit, screen-orientation

I am trying to build an app in Swift 5 which has a locked VC in potrait mode. In the next VC i want the orientation to support all orientations. I have tried several different solutions and none of them seem to work. I don't have Navigation Controller or TabBar. My application is now locked in potrait on both VC:s. I do support different device orientations in the general settings tab.

This is my current code in AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all
}
```

First VC:

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
}

override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait
}
```

Second VC:

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all
}
```

Comment: Use this link answer is available on first post-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938660/how-to-lock-orientation-of-one-view-controller-to-portrait-mode-only-in-swift. if again facing same issue, Let me know.

Comment: try with separate UIWindow for both case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is unfortunately a tricky subject. But if you have no `UINavigationController` or `UITabBarController` it should be straightforward.

In the `AppDelegate`, like you've already done, put:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
  .all
}
```

In the first UIViewController set:

```
// This stops the controller from rotating
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
  false
}

// This will rotate it back to portrait once it's presented again
override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
  .portrait
}
```

In the second one you don't need anything because `shouldAutorotate` defaults to `true`.

**NOTE**: If you aren't using a `UINavigationController` you are probably presenting the second controller. The second controller **has to have** a `modalPresentationStyle` of either `.fullScreen` or `.currentContext`.

I tried it in a sample project and it's the only way I got it to work.

Answer (score 2):

**1, First of all, enable all orientation in Info.plist.**

**2, Create protocol anywhere**

```
protocol RotatableViewController {
    // No content necessary, marker protocol
}
```

**3, Add this to Appdelegate:**

```
extension AppDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        guard let rootVc = self.topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: window?.rootViewController), rootVc.isBeingDismissed == false, let _ = rootVc as? RotatableViewController else { return .portrait } //swiftlint:disable:this all
        return .allButUpsideDown
    }

    private func topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: UIViewController!) -> UIViewController? {
        if rootViewController == nil {
            return nil
        }
        if rootViewController.isKind(of: UITabBarController.self) {
            guard let root = rootViewController as? UITabBarController else { return UITabBarController() }
            return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: root.selectedViewController)
        } else if rootViewController.isKind(of: UINavigationController.self) {
            guard let root = rootViewController as? UINavigationController else { return UINavigationController() }
            return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: root.visibleViewController)
        } else if rootViewController.presentedViewController != nil {
            return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: rootViewController.presentedViewController)
        }
        return rootViewController
    }
}
```

**4, Add RotatableViewController to your controllers, where you want to enable rotation.**

`class ViewController: UIViewController, RotatableViewController`

Comment: Make sure that "Requires full screen" is checked in Target Settings -> General -> Deployment Info. supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor delegate will not get called if that is not checked.

Comment: nice approach, but prefer naming `Rotatable` instead of `RotatableViewController`

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` declare in your Info.plist?

You may turn it on in target config panel:
[image: device orientation]

Next, remove `application(_:supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor:)` method in your AppDelegate. Just declare them in your view controllers.

Comment: I tried to remove application(_:supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor:) and the device orientation is already checked as you proposed. It is still stuck in potrait mode for all VCs.

Comment: @olle do you have a demo project?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[image]
Step 1:
Add below code in your project.

```
struct AppUtility {
    
    static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask) {
        
        if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
            delegate.orientationLock = orientation
        }
    }
    
    /// OPTIONAL Added method to adjust lock and rotate to the desired orientation
    static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask, andRotateTo rotateOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientation) {
        
        self.lockOrientation(orientation)
        
        UIDevice.current.setValue(rotateOrientation.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
        UINavigationController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
    }
    
}
```

Step 2:
Add below code in AppDelegate class.

```
var orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return self.orientationLock
}
```

Step 3:
Add below code in First view controller for lock potrait orientation.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        AppUtility.lockOrientation(.portrait, andRotateTo: .portrait)
}
    
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        //When controller Disappear unlock all orientation for other controllers.
        AppUtility.lockOrientation(.all)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add some utility like this

```
   static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask) {
    if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
        delegate.orientationLock = orientation
    }
   }


static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask, andRotateTo rotateOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
    self.lockOrientation(orientation)
    UIDevice.current.setValue(rotateOrientation.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
    UINavigationController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
}
```

and call it like this on view_willappear and view_willdisappear respectively

```
Utility.lockOrientation(.portrait, andRotateTo: .portrait)
```

in AppDelegate return the value of orientationlock in below delegate method

```
 var orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all

func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
  return orientationLock 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Swift 4, 5+**

Just add this line on your `ViewController`:

```
public override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all
    }
```

For `Portrait` only:

```
public override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
    }
```

For `Landscape`:

```
public override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscape
    }
```

Or can set `landscapeLeft`, `landscapeRight`

Hope it will work for you.