# Locking screen orientation in iOS 14

Tags: ios

I am updating an old iPad app, but I'm unable to stop iOS from rotating a controller that should only be viewed in portrait mode. The app has a `UISplitViewController`, but at one point I need to present another controller fullscreen in portrait mode regardless of whether the iPad was in portrait or landscape before.

I have two issues:

- If the UI was in landscape mode, the portrait view controller also appears in landscape
- The rotation is no longer blocked, so the user can rotate the device even if the controller was displayed in the correct orientation

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller?language=objc#1652793) says that all rotation-related methods were deprecated in iOS 8, and instead iOS will call viewWillTransitionToSize on the window's root viewcontroller. I am therefore calling `[window setRootViewController]` to setup my portrait-only controller, and indeed iOS calls `viewWillTransitionToSize` on my controller. However, at that point it's already too late! I need to stop the transition before it begins.

After spending many hours googling and trying variations, I am no closer to a solution – there is so much old stuff on the 'net (and here on Stack Overflow) that it's really hard to find current information.

I have tried setting `modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen` both in `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`, and then overriding `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation`. My override is never called.

I still have the old methods `supportedInterfaceOrientations`, `shouldAutorotate` and `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`, but none of them is ever called.

I tried implementing `application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow` in my app delegate, but the method is never called. (from the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938660/how-to-lock-orientation-of-one-view-controller-to-portrait-mode-only-in-swift))

What's the correct way of doing this on iOS 14? Should I use a modal full-screen presentation? Or use the trait environment with `UITraitCollection` somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot by any means prevent an iPad app that *can* assume all four rotational position from *actually* assuming all four rotational positions, unless you explicitly opt out of iPad multitasking.

To do so, set the *Info.plist* key `UIRequiresFullScreen` to `YES`; you can do that conveniently while editing the app target by checking Requires Full Screen in the General tab.

But Apple warns that this option is slated to be removed; multitasking will become a requirement and thus rotation to any position will be required as well. Basically it would be better to change your desires.

Comment: Thank you matt, 
I had already checked "Requires full screen" in the app target's general tab. It had no effect, but I found that there are _two_ flags for this in the Info.plist file: `UIRequiresFullScreen` and `UIRequiresFullScreen-ipad`. Once I set the iPad flag to yes in the `<target>-Info.plist`, it worked perfectly!

Comment: It’s silly to have both flags, as this setting is meaningful only on iPad anyway.  Just deleting the second one would be enough. The introduction of the second flag was a bug all along. Delete it and let the first one do its job.

Comment: But, as I say, you would probably do better to accept the inevitable and let the device rotate.

Comment: Yes, if I designed the app today I would do so – but this is an ancient app from 2009 that I'm keeping alive. If/when multitasking becomes mandatory I realize I'll have to do more rework, but for now I am happy to have a working app!

Answer (score 0):

I had asked a simmilar Question for an Ipad but i got closed because of this Question.
My Solution for Ipad IOS 14.5 and VisualStudio2019 was adding these Lines in the InfoPlist.
(For beginners Like me: don't open the Manifest Mask, rightclick the "infoPlist" unter the IOS Header and select "view Code".) Then add these Missing lines:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>    <!--For Vertikal-->
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string> <!--For Horizontal-->
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string> <!--For Horizontal-->
</array>
```