# How can I force screen to rotate to portrait but not upside down in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I would like to rotate certain view controllers to portrait but not upside down, i.e the physical Home button is at the bottom. How could I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to lock orientation of one view controller to portrait mode only in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938660/how-to-lock-orientation-of-one-view-controller-to-portrait-mode-only-in-swift)

Answer (score -1):

If you need a specific view controller to lock to portrait and other view controllers can have any orientation, first keep all the device orientation mode unticked (If you untick all, automatically it'll be set to all orientation) or tick all.

Then in the specific view controller where you want to keep it portrait add the below code,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue
    UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations:      UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .landscapeLeft
}

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use this in production because of the private API.

Comment: When asking questions, you have to mention your requirements also